# Query NOT Workinng in OPEN OFFICE BASE

Tags: database-design, dbms

```
select *  from "StudentMaster" where "PhoneNo" = NULL;
```

Syntax error!

i want to see all record which don't Have Phone number !

I have try this all thing.

```
select *  from "StudentMaster" where "PhoneNo" NOT LIKE ('%');

select *  from "StudentMaster" where "PhoneNo" NOT IN ('%');
```

But it show all record which have Phone Numbers but NOT NULL! Why

Comment: Try `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL` -- Not sure on Open Office Base, but that may work.

Comment: @MarkStewart thanks it's worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer since it solved the problem:

Try `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL` -- I forget that myself sometimes!

I think someone that knows about mathematics would say the `NULL` is nothing so an equals comparison does not work as expected.